# Passing quoted parameters to nodemon on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, batch-file, command-line, nodemon

I want to use nodemon in all of my development scripts. In general it is very straight forward. Just replace "node" for "nodemon".

Except for two problems. One small the other big.

The small problem is that node accepts as its first parameter the script name without the .js extension, while nodemon requires it. This is easy to fix, but annoying, specially when I have several dozens of scripts, bat files and npm packages to review.

The big problem is that node accepts quoted parameters, while nodemon does not, or at least I don't know how to do it.

To reproduce this, just try the following

a very simple node script `soparms.js` that just contains one line of code

```
console.log('\n',JSON.stringify(process.argv.slice(2)),'\n');
```

and the two runs, with `node`

```
> node soparms.js "my test file.txt"

["my test file.txt"]
```

and with `nodemon`

```
> nodemon soparms.js "my test file.txt"
[nodemon] 1.9.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node soparms "my test file.txt"`

["\"my","test","file.txt\""]

[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

any enlightenment?